# Using C++ class in D

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, d

I am trying to find a way to use C++ classes in D.

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/cpp_interface.html

> D cannot call C++ special member functions, and vice versa. These include constructors, destructors, conversion operators, operator overloading, and allocators.

So, I am attempting to dumb down these C++ functions to C style function calls. Here is the proof I am working with.

### helper.h

```
class someClass {
    public:
        someClass();
        char *whatSayYou();
};

extern "C"
{
    someClass *hearMeOut();
}
```

### helper.cpp

```
#include "helper.h"

someClass::someClass()
{

}

char *someClass::whatSayYou()
{
    return "Everything is gravy";
}


someClass *hearMeOut()
{
    return new someClass;
}
```

### main.d

```
import std.stdio;

int main(string[] args)
{
    someClass *awesomeExample = hearMeOut();
    char *shoutoutToTheWorld = awesomeExample.whatSayYou();
    writefln(std.string.toString(shoutoutToTheWorld));
    return 0;
}


extern (C++)
{
    interface someClass
    {
        char *whatSayYou();
    }

    someClass *hearMeOut();
}
```

And here is how I complied it.

```
g++-4.3 -c -I code/dg3d_helper -I /usr/local/include/ -o code/dg3d_helper/helper.o code/dg3d_helper/helper.cpp
code/dg3d_helper/helper.cpp: In member function ‘char* someClass::whatSayYou()’:
code/dg3d_helper/helper.cpp:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
gdc-4.3 -g -c -I code/ -o code/main.o code/main.d
gdc-4.3 -g -I code/ -o main code/dg3d_helper/helper.o code/main.o -lstdc++
```

And I get a segmentation fault as soon as the method is called.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402fa0 in _Dmain (args=...) at code/main.d:7
7       char *shoutoutToTheWorld = awesomeExample.whatSayYou();
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000402fa0 in _Dmain (args=...) at code/main.d:7
#1  0x000000000041b1aa in _D9dgccmain211_d_run_mainUiPPaPUAAaZiZi2goMFZv ()
#2  0x000000000041b235 in _d_run_main ()
#3  0x00002aaaab8cfc4d in __libc_start_main () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000402d59 in _start ()
```

Comment: Will GDB work with D?  At least that [or something like it] would tell you where to start looking.  Debuggers FTW

Comment: You can also build the latest SWIG from SVN and use it (it supports D thanks to klickverbot's work).  I'm trying to learn to use it myself to wrap Irrlicht (in my spare time).

Comment: I am very overwhelmed with all the options in gdb. All I know how to do at this point is backtrace. I am not sure what else it can do to help me figure out the problem.

Comment: I get the segmentation fault compiling the example from the D documentation. I think you have a compiler bug here. Best to report it.

Comment: Also, regarding GDB, try using print variableName

Comment: maybe problem is in `someClass *awesomeExample = ...`. You don't need that asterisk. IIRC this way you declare pointer to reference. If that's the case, you also should modify `hearMeOut()` prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not exposed a C interface. You still have your function returning a C++ class rather than something recognizable by C. Expose your class as `void *`s instead. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
//private members
public:
//public members
    int MyMethod(int argument) const;
    virtual float MyVirtualMethod();
    virtual ~MyClass() {}
};

class MySecondClass : public MyClass
{
public:
    virtual float MyVirtualMethod();
    int MyMethod2(int argument) const;
};

extern "C" {
    void * CreateMyClass()
    {
        return static_cast<void *>(new(std::nothrow) MyClass);
    }

    void * CreateMySecondClass()
    {
        //Note the cast to the base class first (This is needed
        //because it might actually change the position of the pointer,
        //which would not be automatically adjusted later)
        return static_cast<void *>(static_cast<MyClass *>(new(std::nothrow) MySecondClass));
    }

    int CallMyClassMethod(void * thisMember, int argument)
    {
        return static_cast<MyClass *>(thisMember)->MyMethod(argument);
    }

    float CallMyVirtualMethod(void * thisMember)
    {
        return static_cast<MyClass *>(thisMember)->MyVirtualMethod();
    }

    int CallMyMethod2(void thisMember, int argument)
    {
        MyClass * convertedToMyClass = static_cast<MyClass *>(thisMember);
        MySecondClass * asSecondClass = dynamic_cast<MySecondClass *>(convertedToMyClass);
        if (!asSecondClass)
        {
            //Return error (thisMember not an instance of MySecondClass)
        }
        else
        {
            return asSecondClass->MyMethod2(argument);
        }
    }

    void DestroyMyClass(void * classMember)
    {
        delete static_cast<MyClass *>(classMember);
    }
}
```

This will make your class usable by D, but also by C (and every other language that binds to C) as well.

Comment: Unlike every other programming language out there, D doesn't actually need a pure C interface. D allows for partial C++ compatibility. See the page he linked at the top of the question.

Comment: @Ken: Yes, but if one is going to take the time to expose it as a C interface, one should probably expose a C interface. ;). D *does* know how to turn void * into whatever the OP wants, right? (Not sure, never programmed in D before)

Comment: @Billy: Using a void* is probably not that smart, I'd much rather just use a direct MyClass*- it doesn't matter once you export from a DLL but helps maintain safety and sanity in the C++ world.

Comment: @DeadMG: Err.. I don't understand. You'd not be able to compile the C header if you used some class pointer because the class wouldn't exist in C. :/

Comment: @Billy ONeal: it takes a fraction of the work to expose the interface if the only thing you have to wrap is the constructor.

Comment: @Billy: Thanks, I like this solution a little better. Even if it is more typing it is less black magic.

Comment: @Ken: Good point :) @Jacks_Depression: thank you :) One thing I forgot in my above examples is exception handling -- you can't leak exceptions out of the C interface (but I'm sure you already knew that). (That would have a try/catch inside your C function that turns exceptions into error codes)

Answer (score 7):

Your C++ version returns by value.

Your D version expects it to return by reference.

Essentially, your C++ version sticks a copy of someClass on the stack. D thinks that C++ will have put a pointer on the stack. It tries to interpret the copy of someClass as a pointer, and bad things happen.

The problem is that in D, classes and interfaces are always returned by reference. C++ returns everything by value unless you indicate that its either a reference or a pointer.

Thus you need this:

```
someClass * hearMeOut() { return new someClass; }
```

Don't forget to delete it later.

Comment: +1 because this answer maintains compatibility with virtual functions, which my answer makes difficult.

Comment: Nope. Still the same result.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402fa4 in _Dmain (args=...) at code/main.d:7
7     char *shoutoutToTheWorld = awesomeExample.whatSayYou();

Comment: @Jacks_Depression, you can only call virtual functions this way.

Comment: @Winston: Most of the functions I am trying to call are virtual. But if I need to call some that are not. Is there a solution different than that of Billy ONeal?

Comment: @Jacks_Depression, I don't believe D has support for calling the non-virtual methods. You'd probably have to use Billy's method. (If it were me, I'd use gccxml to parse my C++ header file, use the resulting xml file to generate a C wrapper on the C++ and a D wrapper class on the C wrappers. Then I could just use my C++ class in D naturally. But that may be more effort then is worthwhile.)

Comment: @Winston: The gccxml method is approximately what SWIG does.

Comment: @Ken Bloom, with swig you'd have to maintain a bunch of interface files. (unless something has changed). GCCXML should allow you to extract the necessary information from the original files. Other then that, they are the same

Answer (score 0):

D can only call virtual C++ methods with the interface trick.

Furthermore you tell D hearMeOut() used C++ calling convention and C++ it has C calling conv. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should yield problems too.

Imo interfacing with C++ this way is practically limited to calling simple functions since in most C++ libraries you always have non-virtual methods, operators and whatever else in classes, not to mention namespaces which D can't cope with as well.

D SFML does it the way Billy described. It's a tedious job to maintain the C wrapper plus the D wrapper.
Some (semi-)automatic approach like SWIG should be used, then you also get nice cross-language polymorphism.